# Uispy Return's Value as "?"

Tags: .net, ui-automation, inspect, ui-spy

i am using UISpy to detect the outlook TO Address Field but uispy return the Values as "?"

[image: check Here]

If it's normal text then Uispy detects correctly it's showing the To Address. the problem is when we enter any email address in To address field its converting into hyperlink how can we get the to Address using Ui spy.

Comment: Did you try Inspect (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx)? UISpy is obsolete (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Same inspect and UISPY return's me the same result that is '?'....

Answer (score 3):

Inspect.exe from [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) seems to be able to find the email address:

[image: Inspect (with focus in the 'to' field of the email]

[image: Test message]

(using Outlook 2016 on Windows 10)